# Why can't Heroku find a folder my computer can?

Tags: javascript, heroku, discord.js

My discord bot runs on my computer when I use node index.js but when I do the same thing in the heroku terminal I get the following error which is odd because ./commands is a folder in the connected github and it's working fine on my computer.

```
node:internal/fs/utils:344
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './commands'
    at Object.readdirSync (node:fs:1390:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:19:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'scandir',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: './commands'
```

Comment: You could try to clone the heroku code: `heroku git:clone -a APP-NAME` locally to ensure the folder is there - that might help to point you in the right direction

Comment: Wouldn't that be using heroku git and not running it through github?

Comment: Yes - the point would be to inspect what made it on Heroku from your gh deploy - perhaps some ignore file etc could have caused the `commands` folder to be missing hence a way to view what Heroku has. If you do see the expected folder and an index.js in there then you can look somewhere else for issue. I feel it's good to eliminate missing folder/file issues right off the bat

Comment: @cyberwombat I see the commands folder is definitely there in the build. Are they any other possible problems that could cause this?

Comment: What is the code that generates this error? How are you defining the directory you're trying to access? If it's just `./commands`, that's a relative path that depends on the current working directory. Making it relative to some known location, like your `index.js`, would be much more robust.

Comment: The code is ```client.commands = new Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));```. How would you recommend redefining it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are probably calling the Heroku script from a lower folder - the `fs` file system runs [relative to the current working directory](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_string_paths) and not relative to the script you called. The solution is to make the path absolute:

```
fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './commands'))
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixes it!